# Apply filter on content.body()

Tags: python, mako

I have a mako filter that strips html tags. It works fine in other cases.

I have a def that looks something like:

```
<%def name='striptags()'>
    ${ caller.body() | strip_tags }
</%def>
```

This for some reason doesn't work. It seems to me that mako filters don't work when using `caller.body()`. Whenever I check the value of caller.body() using `ipdb` it is always `u''`, but when I see the rendered version in browser the content actually exists.

So, what is happening, and is it possible to apply a mako filter to `caller.body()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

`body = capture(self.body)`

..and passing that to your strip_tags function? You said it doesn't strip tags, but that isn't a built in function -- maybe the problem is with the function and not the `content.body()` portion?

Comment: Ahh, so the strip_tags function works fine when I use it on normal variables like `${ user.first_name | strip_tags }`. For some reason, it just didn't work with `content.body()`. Updated my question to reflect that better.

Comment: Oops I meant, caller.body!

Comment: I used: `capture(context['caller'].body)`